# "Non seulement ... Mais" coupé en deux phrases

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, ponctuation

Ce type de formulation est-il acceptable ?

> Ces choses ont non seulement tendance à faire [... phrase très
>   longue]. Mais elles ont aussi tendance à faire [... phrase
>   encore plus longue].

Answer (score 3):

François Rabelais, icône incontournable de la langue française, dans ce style dense, touffu et foisonnant qui fut le sien, écrivait déjà, **en séparant les deux parties en deux phrases distinctes comme il est proposé dans la question**, en son *Quart livre*, il y a bientôt un demi-millénaire :

<sub>**(Pour ceux que le moyen français rebute, je fais suivre d’une modernisation partielle, plus digeste.)**</sub>

> *Comment Gaſter inuentait art & moyen de non eſtre bleſſe ne touche par coups de Canon.*
>
> **Chapitre LXII.**
>
> Eſt aduenu que Gaſter retirant Grain es fortereſſes s’eſt veu aſſailly des ennemis, ſes fortereſſes demolies par ceſte triſcaciſte & infernale machine : ſon Grain & Pain tollu & ſaccaigé par force Titanique, il inuentoit lors art & moyen **non** de conſeruer ſes rempars, baſtions, murailles, & defenſes de telles canonneries, & que les boulletz ou ne les touchaſſent, & reſtaſſent coy & court en l’air, ou touchans ne portaſſent nuiſance ne es defenſes ne aux citoyens defendens. A ceſtuy inconuenient ia auoit ordre treſbon donné & nous en monſtra l’effet : duquel a depuys uſé Fronton, & eſt de præſent en uſaige commun entre les paſſetemps & exercitations honeſtes des Telemites. L’effay eſtoit tel. Et dorenauant ſoiez plus faciles à croire ce que aſceuré Plutarche auoit experimenté. Si vn trouppeau de Cheures s’en fuyoit courant en toute force, mettez vn brin de Erynge en la gueule d’vne derniere cheminante, ſoubdain toutes s’arreſteront.
>
> Dedans vn faulconneau de bronze il mettoit ſus la pouldre de canon curieuſement compoſee, degreſſee de ſon ſoulfre, & proportionnee auecques Camphre fin, en quantité competente, vne ballote de fer bien qualibree, & vingt & quatre grains de dragee de fer, vns ronds & ſphericques, aultres en forme lachrymale. Puys ayant prins ſa mire contre vn ſien ieune paige, comme s’il le vouluſt ferir parmy l’eſtomach, en diſtance ſoixante pas, on mylieu du chemin entre le paige & le Faulconneau en ligne droicte ſuſpendoit ſur vne potence de bois à vne chorde en l’air vne bien groſſe pierre Siderite, c’eſt à dire Ferriere, aultrement appellee Herculiane, iadis touuee en Ide on pays de Phrygie par vn nommé Magnes comme atteſte Nicander. Nous vulgairement l’appellons Aymant. Puys mettoit le feu on Faulconneau par la bouche du puluerin. La pouldre conſommee aduenoit que pour euiter vacuité (laquelle n’eſt toleree en Nature, plus touſt ſeroit la machine de l’Vniuers, Ciel, Air, Terre, Mer, reduicte en l’antique Chaos, qu’il aduint vacuité en lieu du monde) la ballote & dragees eſtoient impetueuſement hors iectez par la gueule du Faulconneau, afin que l’air penetraſt en la chambre d’icelluy, laquelle aultrement reſtoit en vacuité eſtant la pouldre par le feu tant ſoubdain conſommee. Les ballote & dragees ainſi violentement lancees ſembloient bien debuoir ferir le paige : mais ſur le poinct qu’elles approchoient de la ſuſdicte pierre, ſe perdoit leur impetuoſité, & toutes reſtoient en l’air flottantes & tournoyantes à tour de la pierre, & n’en paſſoit oultre vne tant violente feuſt elle, iuſques au paige. **Mais** il inuentoit l’art & maniere de faire les boulletz arriere retourner contre les ennemis, en pareille furie & dangier qu’ilz ſeroient tirez, & en propre parallele.

---

> *Comment Gaster inventait art et moyen de non être blessé ni touché par coups de canon.*
>
> **Chapitre LXII.**
>
> Est advenu que Gaster retirant Grain ès forteresses s’est vu assailli des ennemis, ses forteresses démolies par cette triscaciste et infernale machine : son Grain et Pain tollu et saccagé par force Titanique, il inventait [dès] lors art et moyen **non** de conserver ses remparts, bastions, murailles, et défenses de telles canonneries, et que les boulets ou ne les touchassent, et restassent coi et court en l’air, ou [que] touchant ne portassent nuisance ni ès défenses ni aux citoyens défendants. À cet inconvénient déjà avait ordre trèsbon donné et nous en montra l’effet : duquel a depuis usé Fronton, et est de présent en usage commun entre les passetemps et exercitations honnêtes des Télémites. L’effet était tel. Et dorénavant soyez plus faciles à croire ce que assuré Plutarque avait expérimenté. Si un troupeau de Chèvres s’en fuyait courant en toute force, mettez un brin d’Erynge en la gueule d’une dernière cheminante, soudain toutes s’arrêteront.
>
> Dedans un faulconneau de bronze il mettait sus la pouldre de canon curieusement composée, dégraissée de son soufre, et proportionnée avec Camphre fin, en quantité compétente, une ballote de fer bien calibrée, et vingt-quatre grains de dragée de fer, [les] uns ronds et sphériques, [les] autres en forme lachrymale. Puis ayant pris sa mire contre un sien jeune page, comme s’il le voulut férir parmi l’estomac, en distance soixante pas, au milieu du chemin entre le page et le Faulconneau en ligne droite suspendait sur une potence de bois à une corde en l’air une bien grosse pierre Sidérite, c’est à dire Ferrière, autrement appellée Herculiane, jadis touvée en Ide au pays de Phrygie par un nommé Magnes comme atteste Nicander. Nous vulgairement l’appellons Aimant. Puis mettait le feu au Faulconneau par la bouche du pulvérin. La poudre consommée advenoit que pour éviter vacuité (laquelle n’est tolerée en Nature, plus tôt serait la machine de l’Univers, Ciel, Air, Terre, Mer, réduite en l’antique Chaos, qu’il advint vacuité en lieu du monde) la ballote et dragées étaient impétueusement hors jetés par la gueule du Faulconneau, afin que l’air pénétrât en la chambre d’icelui, laquelle autrement restait en vacuité étant la poudre par le feu tant soudain consommée. Les ballote et dragées ainsi violentement lancées semblaient bien devoir férir le page : mais sur le point qu’elles approchaient de la susdite pierre, se perdait leur impétuosité, et toutes restaient en l’air flottantes et tournoyantes autours de la pierre, et n’en passait outre une tant violente fut-elle, jusques au page. **Mais** il inventait l’art et manière de faire les boulets arrière retourner contre les ennemis, en pareille furie et danger qu’ils seraient tirés, et en propre parallèle.

D’accord, il n’utilise pas *non seulement*, mais seulement *non*, et les règles de ponctuations différaient un peu à cette époque par rapport à aujourd’hui, bien qu’elles n’étaient pas non plus dépourvues de logique. C’était aussi avant la création de l’Académie française, future gardienne et dépositaire de la langue française.

On ne saurait recommender non plus ce style qui s’étend et s’étend, car il peut s’avérer difficile d’y repérer l’opposition. En effet, même des spécialistes de Rabelais ont manqué d’observer cette opposition marquée à un paragraphe et une dizaine de phrases de distance : le recueil des [Œuvres complètes](http://www.la-pleiade.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Bibliotheque-de-la-Pleiade/OEuvres-completes91) de François Rabelais, publié dans la prestigieuse *Bibliothèque de la Pléiade* chez Gallimard, nous propose (proposait ?) de traduire ce « mais » indiqué en caractère gras dans l’extrait par « de plus », la compilatrice du texte, la [professeure Mireille Huchon](http://lettres.sorbonne-universite.fr/HUCHON-Mireille?lettre=h), ayant plus tard approuvé ma lecture de cet extrait dans un bref échange de courriels que nous fîmes. On trouve aussi un exemple de l’interprétation correcte [ici](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lqiaAwjqsUcC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=triscaciste&source=bl&ots=k9z6DZU_Yu&sig=kCoCTljDfChBKeiu1yan0ELSrjE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC_5qImoTfAhVuzlkKHRZMDDsQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=triscaciste&f=false), en anglais toutefois.

Néanmoins, pour une séparation moindre, disons une seule phrase comme indiqué dans la question, on pourra du moins invoquer Rabelais pour justifier le tour. Pour peu que ça demeure compréhensible et clair, ça devrait passer.

---

Peut-être, cependant, que le fait que seulement *non* soit utilisé dans l’exemple cause-t-il un problème, car après tout, on a en [d’autres réponses](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32736/13100) déclaré que la structure *« non seulement [...], mais [...] »* ne s’échelonne pas naturellement sur deux phrases, objection qui me semble fondée et valide.

Mais si la portion intermédiaire est longue *(ce qui est l’une des spécifications initiales de la question)*, **un point** pourrait peut-être mieux qu’une simple virgule indiquer que l’on revient à nos moutons, bien qu’**un point-virgule** pourrait aussi convenir. Si par ailleurs, la portion intermédiaire doit elle-même être coupée à un certain moment car elle est partie dans trop de directions pour que le fil puisse être facilement suivi, **le point** devient, je crois, la solution à privilégier. Mais voici un exemple qui enchâsse les digressions à la manière d’une poupée russe, qui pourra servir de base à la discussion qui suivra :

- Des penseurs ont **non seulement** tenté de recréer à leur manière les *Éléments* d’Euclide, ce qui n’est pas en soi un crime, car il existe habituellement de nombreuses manières de parvenir à des résultats mathématiques identiques, comme le démontrerait de manière assez éloquente les centaines de démonstrations qui furent construites du fameux théorème de Pythagore, mais peut-être plus encore les travaux du savant poldève N. Bourbaki, qui permirent, en plus d’offrir une structure cohérente recouvrant l’ensemble des connaissances mathématiques de leur époque, de passer à l’ère de LA mathématique, discipline qui avant lui était irrémédiablement plurielle. **Mais** ces penseurs ont même cru pouvoir se passer du cinquième postulat d’Euclide, celui qui déclare que *« si deux lignes droites sont sécantes avec une troisième de telle façon que la somme des angles intérieurs d’un côté est inférieure à deux angles droits, alors ces deux lignes sont forcément sécantes de ce côté »*, axiome auquel on réfère le plus souvent sous la désignation de *postulat des parallèles*.

Le **point-virgule** eût probablement convenu ici, mais si la section intermédiaire avait été plus volubile encore, il vient un moment où le **non seulement** initial sort de la tête du lecteur. Peut-être alors la solution pourrait être d’utiliser non seulement le point, mais de reprendre littéralement le début de la phrase initiale avant de proposer la suite, une méthode éprouvée qu’Alexandre Dumas père et ses collaborateurs utilisèrent à plus d’une reprise :

> Non seulement, disions-nous, des penseurs ont tenté de recréer les *Éléments* d’Euclide, mais ils crurent même pouvoir se passer de [...]

Answer (score 2):

Cette sorte de construction ne se trouve pas ou doit être très rare; il est considéré que « mais » est un élément  de coordination entrant dans une structure corrélative de type « **non seulement … mais** » et selon l'usage établi, cette structure ne s'étage pas sur deux phrases, même consécutives. Il est vrai que « mais » ici est grammaticalement équivalent à « et » et que si « et » ne doit pas, selon l'usage traditionnel, débuter une phrase, il n'est plus exactement vrai de nos jours qu'il n'y ait pas de phrases commençant par « et », on en trouve. De là à justifier que la séparation en deux phrases découle n'est pas une question de stricte logique; on commence bien aussi des phrases par « mais » en français et dans ce cas, en les mots du TLFi « *« Mais » s'emploie en tête d'un énoncé en réaction à une situation dont le locuteur refuse telle ou telle conséquence ou telle ou telle conclusion qu'on pourrait en tirer* »; donné cette fonction, il y a une interférence possible avec celle qui est « *d'ajouter* » à ce qui précède dans la structure « non seulement … mais » : on peut ne plus comprendre que l'on « *ajoute* » mais que dans la phrase précédente on n'a fait que mentionner qu'il y avait d'autres choses que cependant l'on ne jugeais pas utile d'identifier spécifiquement ; l'enchainement avec une nouvelle phrase commençant par mais peut alors être conçu comme une réserve.

Exemple d'un tel contexte

> Ces choses ont non seulement tendance à faire des ennuis. Mais elles ont tendance à faire des gens s'intéresser au projet et donc nous les tolérons.

*C'est à dire, par exemple « Ces choses ont non seulement tendance à faire des ennuis ; elles ont aussi tendance à augmenter les frais; (*cela n'est pas à dire*); mais elles ont tendance à faire des gens s'intéresser au projet et donc nous les tolérons. »

Voilà donc un cas où l'ambiguïté ne se résout pas. En conséquence, je n'avise pas de transgresser avec l'usage établi.

Une méthode pour rendre cette structure corrélative effective lorsque les termes sont longs consiste à introduire la première partie dans une première phrase, pratiquement aussi longue que l'on veut, puis de continuer par une nouvelle phrase, faisant débuter celle-ci par une structure « non seulement … mais » où la première partie apparait sous la forme d'un pronom de rappel. Donc, dans le cas présent la construction est comme suit : « Ces choses ont tendance à faire [complément très long]. (ou « ; »)  Non (*ou* non) seulement ont-elles tendance à faire **(tout) cela** mais elles ont aussi tendance à faire [complément très long] ».

Answer (score 2):

Pour ne pas casser la construction « non seulement, mais » en deux phrases — cela risquerait de gêner le lecteur — pourquoi ne pas plutôt couper en deux phrases comme ça ?

> Ces choses n'ont pas seulement une tendance à […belote…]. Elles ont aussi une tendance à  […rebelote…].

On pourra préférer « surtout », ou « de surcroit », à la place de « aussi » en fonction du contexte. Ajouter un adjectif ou un adverbe serait aussi conseillé.

Comment: il ne **me** viendrait pas à l'esprit ici de recommander ***de** surcroit*. ***par** surcroît* éventuellement. Circonflexe ou non et sans pour autant condamner l'expression avec *de*. Juste une question de sens et surtout de syntaxe ici.

Answer (score 1):

Tu fais absolument tout ce que tu veux avec ces trucs. Donc... pourquoi pas comme tu écris.

Pour la forme, je préférerai peut être.

*Ces choses ont tendance à faire non seulement [... phrase 1], mais aussi [... phrase 2].*

Après... ça peut ne pas être très cool pour le lecteur / auditeur aussi. Je ne sais pas ce que tu entends par phrase très longue mais... il ne faudrait pas qu'arrivé à *mais aussi*, il ait oublié... le sujet (ces choses).

Perso... j'aime pas trop.

Comment: Donc, en me basant sur tes préférences (je m’adresse à des lecteurs  progressistes), si je coupe la phrase tout en réussissant à faire en sorte de répéter le sujet, ça passe (pour toi, perso) ?

Comment: @Tout dépend vraiment de ce que tu entends par *phrase très longue* et comment phrase_1 est structurée. Si ce n'est qu'une énumération de substantifs, ça passera si, au contraire elle contient plusieurs propositions subordonnées relatives (dont le sujet est le COD de la précédente)... là... tu peux être sûre que... je renonce à retrouver le sujet de la PP et probablement aussi à écouter / lire phrase_2.

Comment: @Lisa : v.g. pour ci-dessus : *"Ces choses ont tendance à faire non seulement le jardin, la cuisine, la guerre... mais aussi de la musique, de la peinture...*" Oui sans problème. Alors que *"...non seulement la guerre dont l'issue dépend de circonstances qui, selon la température varient en proportion de... mais aussi..."* alors là... non!