# Cohérence de l’orthographe dans un même document

Tags: orthographe, réforme-orthographique-1991

Selon un commentaire [sous cette réponse à une autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7229/13100), on mentionne *(l’emphase est mienne)* :

> La nouvelle orthographe n'a jamais vraiment réussi à supplanter l'orthographe traditionnelle. Comme Un francophone l'a dit, les deux variantes sont correctes, **mais un texte doit être cohérent. Un mot orthographié selon les rectifications dans un texte écrit selon l'orthographe traditionnelle sera considéré mal orthographié,** et vice-versa.

En préparant une réponse ce matin, j’ai trouvé sur [une page d’aide à la rédaction](https://www.rmc-cmr.ca/fr/escadre-academique/redaction-these#num%C3%A9rotation-des-chapitres-et-des-segments) du Gouvernement du Canada, cette note *(à nouveau, l’emphase est de moi)* :

> #### Orthographe et ponctuation
>
> La thèse doit respecter les règles d’orthographe et de ponctuation du français canadien ou international si elle est rédigée en français; ou de l’anglais canadien, britannique ou américain si elle est rédigée en anglais. **Le même ensemble de règles doit être utilisé du début à la fin.**

Il n’est pas précisé qu’un même ensemble de règles doive séparer l’orthographe pré- et post-rectifications de 1991 en deux compartiments étanches, mais ça ne me semble pas non plus exclu.

On pourrait même y lire une version intermédiaire, à savoir qu’un peu à la manière du commentaire cité plus haut, le rédacteur se doive de faire un choix pour chacun des termes révisés en 1991, et en choisisse un et un seul.

Il demeure possible aussi que l’on définisse un ensemble de règles comme l’une des possibilités citées précédemment (version canadienne ou internationale pour la langue français). Je ne suis pas certain.

Par ailleurs, à la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3195) de l’OQLF, on mentionne, en phase avec l’Académie française *(j’ai légèrement modifié la position de l’emphase)* :

> À l’instar de l’Académie française, qui, en 1991, déclarait que les anciennes graphies demeuraient admises et qu’on ne pouvait rejeter les nouvelles graphies, l’Office québécois de la langue française estime que **ni les graphies traditionnelles, ni les nouvelles graphies proposées ne doivent être considérées comme fautives.**

---

D’un point de vue strictement personnel, j’aime assez à mélanger quelques mots dont l’orthographe fut rectifiée, quand je n’ai pas de préférence marquée pour l’une ou l’autre version. Ça m’évite de devoir prendre position quand je juge le choix à peu près équivalent.

Quant aux termes pour lesquels j’ai une préférence, que ce soit pour l’orthographe traditionnelle ou la rectifiée, j’utilise plutôt celle qui me plaît, quitte même à accoler deux mots selon les graphies se trouvent de part et d’autre de la rectification.

- Est-ce vraiment formellement déconseillé par une institution quelconque d’utiliser deux orthographes différentes du même mot dans le même texte, voire dans la même phrase ?
- Sinon, recommende-t-on, dans les références linguistiques généralement estimées, au nom du bon goût ou d’une autre abstraction du même accabit, de ne pas le faire ?
- Quelle est la position des ministères de l’éducation à travers la Francophonie ? À défaut de privilégier une orthographe sur l’autre, y prescrit-on que l’on doive faire un choix et s’y tenir ? Un élève qui écrirai ce qui suit dans une dictée pourrait-il recevoir une faute ?

  > Ce manuel d’histoire saute d’**événement** en **évènement** et nous présente une chronologie à la manière des faits divers de journaux.
- Peut-on citer quelques exemples d’écrits publiés mélangeant les orthographes, si possible même quelques exemples de textes traitant d’autre chose que de l’orthographe ?

Je serais curieux de connaître le point de vue de professeurs de français, entre autres, s’il y en a qui lisent cette question.

---

<sub>Il est parfaitement possible que l’on ait sa propre opinion sur le genre de mélange invoqué dans cette question, et qu’elle lui soit très défavorable. J’accepterais même sans broncher que ma position soit hyper-minoritaire, parce que ce n’est pas au cœur de la question et que je recherche ce qu’auraient pu en dire les autorités linguistiques vers lesquelles on se tourne habituellement pour trouver des réponses à nos interrogations.</sub>

<sub>Mais puisque l’on m’aura apostrophé en commentaire, d’une manière un peu ***bruyante*** et sans mettre de gants blancs, je puis justifier mon usage, quelque peu éclairé qu’il soit, sur la base d’opinions personnelles : j’ai lu et apprécié Rabelais, en moyen-français. J’en fournirai comme preuve [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32750/13100), que n’aurait su, selon moi, composer une personne peu familière avec Rabelais, fut-elle armée de Google.</sub>

<sub>Je suis par ailleurs assez enthousiasmé par les livres de la *Library of America,* qui a pour ligne de conduite dans l’établissement des textes une philosophie que gagnerait à suivre *la Bibliothèque de la Pléiade* (entre autres), et qui s’exprime assez uniformément dans les livres de la collection de cette manière :</sub>

> <sub>Spelling, punctuation, and capitalization are often expressive features and are not altered, even when inconsistent or irregular.</sub>

<sub>Je me permets la fantaisie de croire que la langue française pourrait elle aussi incorporer ce genre d’attitude, même dans les textes « sérieux ».</sub>

<sub>Je suis aussi conscient que mon approche n’est certainement pas la plus populaire, mais je lui accorde suffisamment de crédit pour me permettre de poser cette question. Je présume possible qu’elle ne soit que très rare, sans qu’on ait officiellement pris position à ce sujet. Je n’écarte pas non plus qu’elle puisse s’inscrire à l’encontre de prescriptions officielles, ou plus simplement de recommendations dont l’application est encouragée.</sub>

Comment: ***Quelles raisons*** y aurait-il pour ne pas maintenir la cohérence dans un même document? maitresse et maîtresse dans le même document?

Comment: @Lambie Quelles raisons recevables pourriez-vous invoquer pour venir ***crier*** ici sans même prendre le temps de concevoir une manière cordiale de présenter votre question?

Comment: +1 pour cette équation paradigme. J'ai appris bien des choses !

Comment: J'ai trouvé la note suivante "IL EST PERMIS de mélanger les deux orthographes dans un même texte ou document, puisque les graphies nouvelles et les graphies traditionnelles sont acceptées (aucune n'est fautive)." Ici : http://www.nouvelleorthographe.info/bilan_resume.pdf . Site québécois.

Comment: @Damien Ça me semble un bon début de réponse. Merci!

Answer (score 3):

Si je peux me permettre une position de correcteur (réviseur) indépendant depuis la France, je préciserais les éléments suivants :

1. Les rectifications dites "de 1990" n'ont jamais constitué une révolution majeure. Contrairement aux modifications habituellement étalées sur les 40 ans nécessaires à sortir une édition de son *Dictionnaire*, l'Académie a seulement fait un tir groupé, hétéroclite et tronqué de nombreuses autres idées de modifications. Cela fait, ces modifications **rejoignent les centaines de graphies doubles ou triples** qui parsemaient déjà la 8e édition et sur lesquelles personne ne se posait de question de choix.
2. On peut se demander qui voit **un intérêt à panacher** plusieurs graphies pour un même mot dans le même texte. Dès lors que plusieurs sont acceptées, on choisit et on mémorise celle qu'on estime la meilleure et on la garde. Seule la ferme opposition d'un éditeur ou d'un particulier autoédité viendra éventuellement en opposition au cas pas cas. La variabilité d'un mot (ou d'une règle) au sein d'un même ouvrage peut apparaitre comme de la négligence.
3. La **nature du texte** peut jouer un rôle : un texte pour la jeunesse (nouvelles graphies encouragées par l'Éducation nationale) n'est pas à mettre sur le même plan qu'un ouvrage historique ou un roman.
4. Le lexique d'usage est loin d'être la seule pomme de discorde potentielle : les ouvrages de référence, grammaticaux ou typographiques, grouillent d'options diverses pour lesquelles le rédacteur ou le correcteur doit faire des choix. Celui des variantes lexicographiques ne fait que s'y ajouter.

Tout cela peut paraitre affligeant car non seulement la langue française écrite est anormalement complexe, mais les variantes et incertitudes sont permanentes : les querelles fréquentes entre spécialistes en attestent. Rien d'étonnant que sur le Vieux Continent, une longue liste de grammairiens, de linguistes et de spécialistes tentent d'élaborer et de promouvoir **un vrai dictionnaire panfrancophone** convivial et cohérent. En France, les premières pierres viennent d'en être posées mais cela touchera toute la Francophonie.

Comment: J'avais mentionné les professeurs de français, mais l'opinion d'un correcteur professionnel est toute aussi intéressante, désolé de l'oubli. J'aurais de nombreuses questions par rapport à bien des points de cette très belle réponse, mais elles ne tiendraient pas en un seul commentaire. Je me contenterai d'une remarque par rapport au point 2, une perception qui, poussée à son extrême, pourrait permettre l'intransigeance face à la variabilité possible de l'orthographe et les attaques indues au contenant d'un message autrement bien réfléchi *(on doit choisir ses combats, bien sûr..).* Merci!

Comment: Un merci chaleureux pour votre appréciation : les quelques centaines de correcteurs qui restent en France (édition, presse, libéraux) déterminent de manière significative de nombreuses graphies qui perdurent. Mais l'obscurité de leur tâche les rend souvent invisibles et muets.

Comment: Pour ce qui est du point 2, je me suis peut-être mal fait comprendre. Il est préférable d'éviter le panachage au sein d'un même ouvrage, non entre différents écrits. Il s'agit surtout de ne pas accrocher l’œil du lecteur (provoquer une interrogation) sur un sujet autre que le contenu même du texte. Il n'y a là aucun dogmatisme…